# Printer driver send to web server

Tags: node.js, pdf, printing, ftp, postscript

I need to "hack" a program to export some data. The only way the program can output is via printing. How can I hijack this? The OS is Windows Embedded.

I was originally thinking "print to pdf" program/spoof printer driver and then ftp to server for processing. However this may require OCR for PDF decode.

Or is there a way to send a postscript stream to a server? I guess postscript would be better as I can decode it easier.

I don't know anything about printers/protocols etc.

Could I source/write an IPP (internet printing protocol) client in node.js and just add it as a normal printer in Windows?

The server software is node.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect the performance of "print to pdf to ftp to OCR decode" will suck. So I have taken on the mammoth task of writing an IPP server in node...

Comment: Did you end up doing this? Looking at doing something very similar!

Comment: @Hemal I see that I have the repo https://github.com/msyea/printb.in-ipp but it looks a bit immature. I recall progressing further on this. Looks like someone has reregistered my domain and done something similar https://github.com/watson/printbin

Comment: Cheers for that. Watson/printbin looks promising. Thanks again!